# Swift Haneke: Json Data in TextView

Tags: ios, json, swift, haneke

I used the Haneke Framework to get Data from a Site.
With the Haneke Framework i also can get  Images from a site, and these Images i can present on a UIImageView.
Now i wanted to get some text from a site.

I did it like this:

```
 cache.fetch(URL: URL).onSuccess { JSON in
            println(JSON.dictionary?["index"])
```

It printed me all the data from "Index".

Now i want, that all the data from "Index" should be presented on a UITextView.

```
  self.textView.text = JSON.dictionary["index"]
```

But it doesn't work. I get the error:

> Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject' to a value of type 'String!'

I have to unwrap it or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this prints out all records of the JSON text. The structure is an array of dictionaries. The text is very simply formatted (two tab characters between key and value).

```
  cache.fetch(URL: url).onSuccess { JSON in
    if let index = JSON.dictionary?["index"] as? [Dictionary<String,String>] {
      var resultString = ""
      for anItem in index {
        for (key, value) in anItem {
          resultString += "\(key)\t\t\(value)\n"
        }
        resultString += "\n\n"
      }
      self.textView.text = resultString
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the compiler doesn't know the type of the dictionary item.
If you know it's always a String make a forced downcast from `AnyObject` to `String`

```
self.textView.text = JSON.dictionary["index"] as! String
```

Comment: But now the app  freezes, after i try to run it. I get following message:  Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x110306650) to 'NSString' (0x1107968e0).

Comment: then the object is an array not a string. What kind of array is it?

Comment: Its actually a String.. Hm,     let cache = Cache<JSON>(name: "test")
        
        let URL = NSURL(string: "myurl")!

Comment: the compiler complains that the object returned from `JSON.dictionary["index"]` is an NSArray object and the compiler is right ;-)

Comment: :D  so what should i do? Do i have to unwrapp it?

Comment: that depends how many objects the array contains. If it's only one write `self.textView.text = (JSON.dictionary["index"] as! [String]).first!`. But with this syntax the app will crash if the array is empty

Answer (score 0):

as we've revealed that `JSON.dictionary["index"]` is an Array, this is a safe syntax **assuming that the array contains only one item**

```
if let indexTextArray = JSON.dictionary?["index"] as? [String] {
  if !indexTextArray.isEmpty {
      self.textView.text = indexTextArray.first!
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay the App works now :) But it doesn't show me anything in my UITextView, is it because, the array only contains one item?

Comment: `println()` the object or set a breakpoint to figure out what kind of array it is

Comment: I did println(index) and i got a lot of "Array of Strings"

Comment: then you could flatten the array by inserting line breaks `if let indexTextArray = JSON.dictionary?["index"] as? [String] { self.textView.text = "\n".join(indexTextArray)  }`

Comment: Okay i can run the app now, but my TextView isn't changing.. Hmm

Comment: do you get a result by `println()` the `"\n".join(indexTextArray)` expression?

Comment: If i do it like this: cache.fetch(URL: URL).onSuccess { JSON in
            println(JSON.dictionary?["index"])  i get lot of results

Comment: sorry, you have to find the proper type of the object and its contents. Look at the printout: `[value, value]` is Array, `[key:value, key:value]` is dictionary

Comment: So how should i do it?

Comment: read the printout as mentioned, log values, set breakpoints, cast to something "impossible" to read the compiler error messages

Comment: What do you mean with  printout [value, value] ?  Why is it actually so hard, to just change the text of the  TextView to something on a Json Site? I just want, that the textview should show everything that is inside of "index".. :/

Comment: the text view needs explicit plain text (String), you have to convert the returned JSON collection type (obviously Array) into String

Comment: Whats the easiest way to convert a array into a string?

Comment: But didn't we actually converted it already with:   
            if let indexTextArray = JSON.dictionary?["index"] as? [String] {
                
                self.textView.text = "\n".join(indexTextArray)
                println(["index"])
                
            }
            
?

Comment: yes, we did, there must be still another issue. Please use the options I gave you to identify the proper types. There could be other nested arrays or dictionaries which causes the conversion to fail

Comment: Okay but i don't know what you mean... How can check the types of "index"? I already did it with println() and it printed me a lot of "String Arrays" If you want, i can give you the URL, that i want to parse...

Comment: Only if you have time, here is the URL: http://www.berlin.de/sen/wirtschaft/service/maerkte-feste/strassen-volksfeste/index.php/index/all.json?q=

Comment: oh, deutsch, gut. :-) Das ist ein Haufen Zeugs. Bist du per email erreichbar? (Oh, german, good. That's a bunch of stuff)

Comment: You are also german :D ?  I  also can speak in english :) btw: It works now! Thank you for your help !! :D

Comment: Yep Thanks! Works now perfectly :)

Comment: Hey i got another question: With SwiftyJson i can perfectly parse the context of "Index" like this:  func ParseJSON(json: JSON) {
        for result in json["index"].arrayValue {
            let title = result["badname"].stringValue
            let body = result["profil"].stringValue
            let sigs = result["id"].stringValue
            let obj = ["title": title, "body": body, "sigs": sigs]
            objects.append(obj)
        }
        
}      Is there also a way to do this with Haneke?